# Add collect PyTables library to PyInstaller SPEC File

Tags: pyinstaller, pytables

I am using PyInstaller to build an executable of a python script containing PyTables.
Since I've updated to the newest version, building the executable fails. The error reads:

```
Error: RuntimeError: Blosc2 library not found. I looked for "libblosc2.dll, C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI10642\tables\libblosc2.dll, None"
```

According to this post, adding tables binary is now needed:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7408

I have a SPEC-File and dont know how to add the missing library. I've tried the following:

So I am trying to add

Case 1:

```
binaries=[('C:\\Python39\\bin\\libblosc2.dll', 'BINARY')]
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: Blosc2 library not found. I looked for "libblosc2.dll, C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI10642\tables\libblosc2.dll, None"
```

Case 2:

```
binaries=[('C:\\Python39\\bin\\libblosc2.dll', '.')]
```

The loader hangs in a loop and not starting the executable.

So, how do I add the "Just add --collect-binaries=tables to your pyinstaller command" properly to my SPEC-File?

Thanks!

System-Info:
INFO: PyInstaller: 6.3.0
INFO: Python: 3.9.7
INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
INFO: tables 3.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same problem. `--collect-binaries=tables` only works for command line. To resolve this issue, you can add the following to your app.spec file:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_dynamic_libs

binaries = []
binaries += collect_dynamic_libs('tables')

a = Analysis(
    ...
    binaries=binaries,
    ...
)
```

If you encountered loader stuck in loop after successfully building the app, you can see the following issue [Loader stuck in loop with PyTables](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/8246)